# porting and backing up databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using sqlite3 in development and mysql in production on a Rails 3.2 app.

I'd like to be able to backup the mysql, and also to create a sqlite copy of it for use in the development environment. Anyone know how to do this, or the preferred way to back up mysql at least?

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to this one, and use it to convert to/from MSSQL, sqlite and MySQL quite a lot:
https://github.com/unixmonkey/rails_db_convert_using_adapters

Answer (score 0):

This may not be feasible if you have a large DB, but I am working with a rather small one (about 10MB). 
**(1)** I back up all of my model classes into a .zip file using a rake task, and then

**(2)** have a button (with admin authentication) that runs another rake task to reload the data.

So I can backup the data in dev/prod mode, push my files to the other environment, and reload the data from backup (it's in .csv files, so it's DB-independent). This worked for me switching between sqlite3 and mysql2 (I am using Rails 4.0.1 if that's relevant).

I can post code if that would be helpful to people, but it's a little messy so I'll save the eyesore unless someone would find it helpful. I've found the .csv into .zip file backup to be a nice workaround for different SQL systems, if you're working on the order of megabytes.